# How to add `ls -la` to the end of each command on the command line?

Tags: bash, command-line, git-bash

I am constantly running `ls -la` after `cd`'ing into folders as I often work on file trees that I'm not familiar with.

This is getting tedious and I would like someway to add `ls` after each time I press enter so I can always see the list of files and folders when I change directory.

I couldn't find much support on google as I wasn't sure what to google.

Comment: The problem then you'll have that, you'll get used to that chained command. But once you connect to another machine, it does not have that chained command, and you're back at step 1. You should get it in your system to use `ls -la`. I use `ll`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set

```
PROMPT_COMMAND='ls -la'
```

It runs the command *before* showing the prompt, i.e. after it runs the command you entered in the command line. In other words, if you're in a directory with many files, you won't see any output of your commands, as it will scroll out because of the prompt command. Maybe using something like

```
PROMPT_COMMAND='ls -la | head -n10'
```

might be better.

Answer (score 1):

Create a function in your .bashrc like

```
mycd() {
  cd "$*" && ls -la
}
```

Edit:
Better is supporting different options/arguments with

```
mycd() {
  cd "$@" && ls -la
}
```

Comment: would this then run after any command or just cd? Or will i have to run `mycd()`?

Comment: It will run when you use `mycd`. Do not call the function `cd`, in that case your function will be calling itself in an endless loop.

Comment: Im looking for something similar but would run on `return` like when i press enter on any command i would want a ls -la to run. I dont mind if it looks a bit weird sometimes

Comment: perhaps should be `"$@"` instead of `"$*"` (cd can take options). you could also do `cd(){ builtin cd "$@"; ...; }`

Comment: I think the answer of @choroba works better when OP really wants it after each command.

Comment: I'm not sure the OP *wants* it after every command, as the `ls` is always mentioned in the context of switching to a new working directory.

Comment: Once you implement a function like `mycd` above and you want to invoke it as `cd`, you can also define an alias by executing `alias cd='mycd'`. Don't worry: this will not enter into an infinite loop.